# Which of the following Delta/Pie to Star/T transformation is correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Here I am trying to transform  pie/delta system into star/T form. But I can't figure out which one is right. Which one is the correct and Why?

[image]